# How do I set Timeout property on Castle Windsor WcfClient

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, castle-windsor, wcf-binding

I have a windows service where I'm invoking a Wcf Client endpoint like this.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking start...");
        using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
        {
            container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IShoppingService>()                        
                    .AsWcfClient(new DefaultClientModel(
                        WcfEndpoint
                            .ForContract<IShoppingService>()
                            .BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None))
                            .At("net.tcp://localhost:12123/shoppingService"))));
            container.Resolve<IShoppingService>().Debug();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking end...");
```

I want to increase the timeout programmatically of the call to 10 mins for debugging purposes. How can I set the timeout property on the client like I normally would do in the bindings section in the app.config file like so

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="longTimeOutLargeTcpBuffer" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="20000000" maxStringContentLength="10000000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>        
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set properties directly on binding:

```
    var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
                      {
                          CloseTimeout = timeout,
                          ReceiveTimeout = timeout,
                          SendTimeout = timeout,
                          OpenTimeout = timeout
                      };
```

then:

```
    .BoundTo(binding)
```